# How to add 4 decimal places as precision while defining Schema in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I am designing a wallet rest api where I am taking wallet balance as request body. I can enter balance as 10.123456 but i want to keep the decimal precision upto 4 places. that is my response gets saved with 10.1234.
What can my approach be?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
const input = 10.123456;
const rounded = Math.floor(input * 10000) / 10000;

console.log(rounded);
```

You can, of course, add this code to your schema directly like:

```
myValue: {
    type: Number,
    set: v => Math.floor(v * 10000) / 10000
  }
```